# fade In div with zoom:150% and display none..doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made the fade in and fade out of one div that contain an img zoomed, that works pretty good in Chrome, FF , Safari. But doesn't work in IE9, the function Fade in and Fade out works good but didn't use the img zoomed, is used the img not zoomed.

```
the stylesheet:

#facearea
{
    zoom:150%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index :1;
       border: 0px black solid;



}

#facearea1
{

z-index: 2;
zoom:150%;
position:absolute;


}  


javascript/text
unction Mode_3_1() 
{ 

document.getElementById('facearea1').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
document.getElementById('facearea').style.visibility = 'visible'; 



document.getElementById('facearea').style.display = 'block'; 
document.getElementById('facearea1').style.display = 'none';
$('#facearea1').fadeIn( 1000 );
}
```

the problem i guess is when i set display='none', is like if after that i set display='non' all the "attributes" of the current div are ignored(e.g. zoom:150% or opacity)

I tried to don't use display:none but .hide() or just change the opacity of the img but still not working

Please Can anyone give me some information about this incevenient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by just putting the `!important` attribute after `zoom:150%`

```
#facearea1,
#facearea
{
    zoom:150%!important;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    border: 0px black solid;
    top:190;
    left:80;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `zoom:1.5;` istead `zoom:150%;`. I hope that will work, because i don't have IE9 to test it.

Comment: I still have the same problem, the fade in works but only with the img without zoom.